# How is my SQL subquery evaluating to more than one row? When run independently, it works fine, but doesn't work in a SELECT subquery

Tags: sql, count, sas, subquery, left-join

I am obtaining values from two tables. When I run the subquery in its own PROC SQL statement in SAS, it runs fine, with the count of citations for each ID. When I input the subquery into my SELECT outer query, it gives me ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row. I am having a hard time determining the cause of this issue.

The subquery should result in one row of count of citations per ID. I am trying to get the count of citations (per ID) into my outer query. Not all items from B will be in A (hence the left join on B).

```
SELECT 
    A.AREA
    ,A.NAME
    ,B.ID
    ,(
        SELECT 
            COUNT(B.TYPE) 
        FROM 
            EVAL.CITATIONS AS B
        GROUP BY 
            B.ID
        ) 
        AS COUNT_CITATIONS

FROM 
    EVAL.OCT AS A 

LEFT JOIN EVAL.CITATIONS 
    ON A.DBA = B.NAME

ORDER BY A.NAME ASC

;
```

I expected the outer query to pull the counts for the citations per ID. The citations are coming from table B (which I'm using to left join into table A). I have been searching forums for this error and I understand that my query is resulting in more than one row, but I can't figure out why the outer query is not simply pulling the counts I need from ID when the left join completes.

I also tried adding in the subquery this WHERE clause after researching some similar questions to no avail.

```
WHERE FACID = CDPH_CITATIONS.FACID
```

Comment: A "scalar subquery" can only return a single row. However, you clearly state that "...it runs fine, with the count of citations for each ID...". That won't work. You'll need to add a filtering condition to the subquery, so it returns a single row at most.

Comment: Why are you joining on A.DBA and B.NAME but keeping neither of them in the results? Show some sample data and the expected results for that sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a correlated subquery where your subquery references your main query e.g.

```
SELECT 
A.AREA
,A.NAME
,B.ID
,(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(C.TYPE) 
    FROM 
        EVAL.CITATIONS AS C
    WHERE B.ID = C.ID
    GROUP BY 
        C.ID
    ) 
    AS COUNT_CITATIONS

FROM 
EVAL.OCT AS A 

LEFT JOIN EVAL.CITATIONS 
ON A.DBA = B.NAME

ORDER BY A.NAME ASC
```

However, I don’t think you need a subquery at all, you can just count the B records and group by the other columns in your main query

Comment: Thank you NickW! I did not need a subquery after all. Adding the count and using the GROUP BY worked. Also, I tried using your solution query, but it still gave me the same error. Time to try to investigate why that is.

Answer (score 1):

Your query fails because the subquery in the `SELECT` clause returns more than one row: it returns the count of each and every `id` in the `citations` table, while you want just the count  of the "current" id. There is also a problem with the scoping of the table identifiers (eg: `B` is defined in the subquery but used in the outer query).

To avoid that, we can *correlate* the subquery with the outer query (and fix the table aliases):

```
SELECT o.AREA, o.NAME, c.ID,
    (SELECT COUNT(c.TYPE) FROM EVAL.CITATIONS WHERE c1.ID = c.ID) AS COUNT_CITATIONS
FROM EVAL.OCT AS o 
LEFT JOIN EVAL.CITATIONS AS c ON c.NAME = o.DBA
ORDER BY o.NAME ASC
```

Now this can be further optimized using window functions; we do nott need to reopen the citations table in a subquery, we can perform a window count instead; this is much more efficient since the table is scanned only once. So:

```
SELECT o.AREA, o.NAME, c.ID,
    COUNT(c.TYPE) OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID) AS COUNT_CITATIONS
FROM EVAL.OCT AS o 
LEFT JOIN EVAL.CITATIONS AS c ON o.DBA = c.NAME
ORDER BY o.NAME ASC
```

Comment: Note that WINDOW functions do not work in PROC SQL.  But you don't need them since SAS will re-merge the aggregate function results back onto the detailed observations.  So just add the group by to the main query.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting multiple values because you did not tell it to only run the subquery for the single value of ID that matched value on the current observation of the outer query.

But in SAS there is no need to get so tricky.  SAS will happily re-merge the aggregate values back onto all observations that share the group by variable values.

```
proc sql;
SELECT 
     A.NAME
    ,A.AREA
    ,B.ID
    ,COUNT(B.TYPE) AS COUNT_CITATIONS
FROM EVAL.OCT AS A 
LEFT JOIN EVAL.CITATIONS B
    ON A.DBA = B.NAME
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY NAME 
;
quit;
```